# Make dynamic selector jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a script in jQuery (2.1.4) who add a button to specific block
Example :

```
<div class="dr_ing_list">
    <?php
        $ingredients=explode(';', $donnee['ingredients']);
        foreach ($ingredients as $value) {
            echo "<p>".$value."</p></br>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
<div class="dr_met_list">
    <?php
        $methode=explode(';', $donnee['methode']);
        foreach ($methode as $value) {
            echo "<p>".$value."</p></br>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

i get the class of each div for make a dynamic selector, but i have an error :
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ".dr_ing_list p:last"

Here's my jQuery script :

```js
var block_button = 0;
$(".fa-lg").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault;
  var categorie = $(this).parent().attr('class');
  var selector = categorie+' p:last';
  selector = '".'+selector+'"';
  alert(selector);
  $(selector).after("<button class='cta' type='button'>Valider les modifications</button>");
});
```

```css
p{
  margin: 0;
}

.dr_ing_list{
  width:300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.dr_met_list{
  width:300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dr_ing_list">
  <button type="button" class="fa-lg">edit</button>
  <p>Butter</P></br>
  <p>Milk</P></br>
  <p>Egg</P></br>
  <p>Flour</P></br>
</div>

<div class="dr_met_list">
  <button type="button" class="fa-lg">edit</button>
  <p>Shake</P></br>
  <p>Don't drink</P></br>
  <p>Re shake</P></br>
  <p>You can drink</P></br>
</div>
```

Where is my error ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

```
selector = '".'+selector+'"';
```

Change it to:

```
selector = '.'+selector;
```

Why? The selector in first case is a string containing: ***"."dr_ing_list 
p:last""*** instead it must be: ***".dr_ing_list p:last"*** (double quotes).

The snippet:

```js
var block_button = 0;
$(".fa-lg").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault;
  var categorie = $(this).parent().attr('class');
  var selector = categorie+' p:last';
  selector = '.'+selector;
  console.log(selector);
  $(selector).after("<button class='cta' type='button'>Valider les modifications</button>");
});
```

```css
p{
  margin: 0;
}

.dr_ing_list{
  width:300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.dr_met_list{
  width:300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="dr_ing_list">
    <button type="button" class="fa-lg">edit</button>
    <p>Butter</P></br>
    <p>Milk</P></br>
    <p>Egg</P></br>
    <p>Flour</P></br>
</div>

<div class="dr_met_list">
    <button type="button" class="fa-lg">edit</button>
    <p>Shake</P></br>
    <p>Don't drink</P></br>
    <p>Re shake</P></br>
    <p>You can drink</P></br>
</div>
```

A reduced form of your code could be:

- [nextAll](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/): Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.
- [jQuery Create element on the fly](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes): in this way you avoid to write html as string, avoiding in this way potential errors

so, the new snippet is:

```js
var block_button = 0;
$(".fa-lg").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  $(this).nextAll('p:last').after($('<button/>', {
    class: 'cta',
    type: 'button',
    text: 'Valider les modifications'
  }));
});
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.dr_ing_list {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dr_met_list {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="dr_ing_list">
    <button type="button" class="fa-lg">edit</button>
    <p>Butter</P></br>
    <p>Milk</P></br>
    <p>Egg</P></br>
    <p>Flour</P></br>
</div>

<div class="dr_met_list">
    <button type="button" class="fa-lg">edit</button>
    <p>Shake</P></br>
    <p>Don't drink</P></br>
    <p>Re shake</P></br>
    <p>You can drink</P></br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

You are ending up with too many quotes

Try changing

```
selector = '".'+selector+'"';
```

To

```
selector = '.'+ selector;
```